# node.js app running fine locally but on deploying on heroku showing lots of errors

Tags: node.js, express, github, heroku, deployment

git repo: https://github.com/pranay101/Vocabook.git

the app runs fine locally but shows

```
2020-06-18T12:26:39.181941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-18T12:26:43.862623+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-18T12:26:43.862662+00:00 app[web.1]: > vocabook@0.0.0 start /app
2020-06-18T12:26:43.862663+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2020-06-18T12:26:43.862664+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940614+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940637+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940638+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940638+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940640+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/schema/User'
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940640+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940640+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/routes/users.js
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940641+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/app.js
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940641+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/bin/www
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940643+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940644+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/users.js:9:20)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940644+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940645+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940646+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940646+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940646+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:13:21)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940647+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940647+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940647+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940648+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14) {
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940648+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940649+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/routes/users.js', '/app/app.js', '/app/bin/www' ]
2020-06-18T12:26:44.940649+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-18T12:26:44.952800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-18T12:26:44.953480+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-06-18T12:26:44.956029+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! vocabook@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
2020-06-18T12:26:44.956352+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-06-18T12:26:44.956667+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-18T12:26:44.956882+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the vocabook@0.0.0 start script.
2020-06-18T12:26:44.957081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-18T12:26:45.013388+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-06-18T12:26:45.013821+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-18T12:26:45.013935+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-18T12_26_44_965Z-debug.log
2020-06-18T12:26:45.089797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-18T12:26:45.145085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-18T12:27:42.690145+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=d3ad5e44-91cd-4c00-bdf4-f0a8db726fb0 fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https       
2020-06-18T12:27:47.505193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=fdbd70e1-8636-4cb4-883a-1e80f0e66b38 fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-18T12:27:54.594076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=f6265824-4eaf-41ad-8b62-747ea5949214 fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https       
2020-06-18T12:27:56.264616+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=03abbb5c-118c-4213-ba85-94ed979f2f18 fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-06-18T12:27:58.659303+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=eb92814f-f94a-467e-aafd-e1d13e0ba18c fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https       
2020-06-18T12:28:00.479668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=voca-book.herokuapp.com request_id=47703397-96db-4b4b-83e7-d40a4d935078 fwd="152.57.22.7" dyno= connect= service= status=503
```

**but mostly the errors are about a module not found, but if it's so then it shouldn't be running locally either.**

what could be the possible reason.

build log:
is this the build log ??
if errors are check during build or after the build.

```
`Build
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        removed 107 packages and audited 245 packages in 2.955s
remote:        
remote:        4 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:
remote:        found 1 low severity vulnerability
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 28.2
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://voca-book.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

`

Comment: post heroku build log.

Comment: Ig that's the build log. Checked using `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: That's not the build log. When deploying an app on Heroku you see it setting up your git environment. Then it checks for the buildpacks. In your case it detected the node buildpack. There is picks up a version. Then it installs the node packages defined in `package.json` (`npm install`). And then comes the build log `npm build`. I also just took a look at your git project and in your `package.json` under `scripts` it is missing `build`. What you provided is the log for `npm start`.

Comment: https://github.com/pranay101/Vocabook/blob/c06cd37d721dfc1d401647c68008ec0a5d1bf5ed/routes/users.js#L9
https://github.com/pranay101/Vocabook/tree/c06cd37d721dfc1d401647c68008ec0a5d1bf5ed/models/schema
`models/schema/User` your file is lowercase.

Comment: I've added build log let me know is this is, what you asked for